# I need help determining what is wrong with my solution to this problem

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is the problem I want to solve in C:

> #### Problem
>
> A war has started between two rival countries A and B. Country A wants to destroy the Capital city of B through aerial bombing. But due to the sudden outbreak of war, the ammunition reserves are low on both sides. Due to less quantity of ammunition, fighter pilot Jeff has been asked to carry the exact number of bombs that are required to destroy the whole city. Each bomb can be dropped on a building only.
>
> Capital of country B is a one dimensional city with n buildings, where each building (i) is located at some x(i) on the x-axis. Jeff has to destroy every building in the city. Each bomb has a destructive range k, meaning it can destroy everything at a distance ≤ k units away from its point of impact.
>
> Now given a map of the city and the range k of the bomb, Jeff wants you to find the minimum number of bombs he needs to destroy the whole city(each building must be in the destructive range of at least one bomb).
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers n(number of buildings in the city) and k(range of destruction of each bomb).
> The second line contains n space-separated integers, depicting the location of buildings on the x-axis.
>
> #### Output
>
> Print a single integer denoting the minimum number of bombs required to destroy the city.

#### Constraints

```
1 ≤ n,k ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ x ≤ 10^5
```

#### Sample Input

```
4 2
1 2 3 4
```

#### Sample Output

```
1
```

[Link to the question.](https://code.dcoder.tech/challenges/algoyo/5cd74bf81681076686ea2ec3/depleting-ammunition)

> Question can also be found at: **code.dcoder.tech > challenges > hard > depleting ammunition**

---

### My Solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Variables named according to the problem
 * n         - number of buildings
 * k         - range of bombs
 * buildings - Array containing the integer
 *             coordinates of the buildings
 */
int n, k, *buildings;

void getInput(void);
int isBuilding(int);
int nextBuilding(int);
int lastBuilding(int);

int main(void) {
 getInput();
 int bombs = 0;
 /* Loops through the x cordinates from building 1 to n
  * i - indicates the x coordinate where jeff is
  * j - indicates the bombed area
  * r - indicates the bomb range
  */
 for (int i = buildings[0], j = (buildings[0] - 1), r = k; i <= buildings[n - 1] || j < buildings[n - 1]; i++, r--) {
  /* When joel leaves bomb range coordinates behind */
  if (r == 0) {
   /* Bomb is only dropped on a building */
   while (!isBuilding(i))
    i--;
   /* Increment bombed area (back, position and front)*/
   j = i + k;
   bombs++;
   r = k + 1; // +1 because the loop makes r--
   /* next building beyond range
    * +1 because we need to leave all bombed area behind
    */
   i = nextBuilding(i + k + 1);
   /* if no building */
   if (i == 0)
    break;
   else
    i--; // the loop will make i++
  }
 }
 printf("%d\n", bombs);
 return 0;
}

/* Ascending comparison for qsort */
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
 const int *aa = a;
 const int *bb = b;
 return (*aa > *bb) - (*aa < *bb);
}

/* Gets input for n, k and buildings,
 * and sorts buildings
 */
void getInput(void) {
 if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2) {
  fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
  return;
 }
 buildings = calloc(sizeof *buildings, n);
 if (!buildings) {
  fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
  return;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (scanf("%d", &buildings[i]) != 1) {
   fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
   return;
  }
 }
 qsort(buildings, n, sizeof *buildings, compare);
}

/* Returns 1 if it is a building,
 *  0 otherwise
 */
int isBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] == p)
   return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}

/* Returns position of next building greater or equal to p,
 * 0 if none available
 */
int nextBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] >= p)
   return buildings[i];
 }
 return 0;
}

/* Returns position of last building less or equal to p
 * 0 if none available
 */
int lastBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] == p)
   return buildings[i];
  else if (buildings[i] > p)
   return buildings[--i];
 }
 return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation

I take a more direct approach the problem since trying to find a formular seemed impossible.

In **main** I use `i` as Jeff's position and he moves `k` (bomb range) distance ahead then place a bomb there if there exists a building at that point, or move back to the last building. (The question explicitly mentions that a bomb can only be placed at a building).

Then I move `i` to the next unbombed building and repeat the above process.

The condition `j < n` is for when there are buildings left but `i <= buildings[n - 1]` cannot be met (`i` has exceeded the last building).

### Issue

The code seems to be working well on my end.

I have tested with various input (some shown below) besides the one in the question and got the desired output.

```
Input:
6 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
Output: 2

Input:
10 2
2 3 8 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
Output: 4
```

**Although when I submit the problem, all tests fail**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I love these real-life examples! Makes programming so much more fun, and relatable. I have a few suggestions: Add the maximum number of hospitals that can be destroyed, and maximize the civilian/military fatality ratio. Also, if you have foot soldiers, how many villages are within reach so that you can massacre their inhabitants before the enemy's troops can be mobilized. How much money could you save if you simply nuked the place instead is a bonus question, but the teacher asking that got reprimanded.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica please read the problem again. Thanks

Comment: I have voted this question for closing.

Comment: You voted your own question for closing? I suppose that is possible, but I also think that every user can simply *delete* their own questions.— By the way, I feel like explaining my comment, perhaps apologize. Even though I'm relatively old (60) and typically easy-going, I *am* affected by the current wars which seem unusually cruel. (Probably just because they are politically and geographically closer than some other, equally atrocious conflicts, but still.) Your question somehow "tickled me wrong", if you know what I mean. It is, I think, interesting, maybe you can reword it.

Comment: One issue may be that an implementation may have 16 bit integers with INT_MAX==32767 while the maximum values are 10^5, aka 100000. I don't know whether that's the point here, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code, but the website's interpretation of **C** solutions.

Re writing the solution in **java** solved the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... that is unsatisfying. Most likely, there is a difference, for example in integer value ranges or such, which leads to an error like an overflow in C but not in Java. I think you are missing the actual problem (which is solved "accidentally" in Java) if you simply go on. These programming problem websites often have questions that have a simple, straight-forward solution which runs too long, leads to an overflow or needs too much memory. Seeing and preventing that is the actual problem. Pay close attention to the value ranges of the question parameters and test some extremes.

Comment: Oh, and if you are stuck you can often "cheat" by looking at other peoples' solutions.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the info...i had no idea about the integer ranges issue. But trust me when i say its the website. Because all **C** solutions fail (not the last one i tried) and i tested my code for *several inputs*. Its just odd that all test cases fail when i submit. (i mean at least some should be correct)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica also i really dont like the cheating part. It defeats the whole point of solving the problem. (to get a worthy challenge :-) ) I enjoy those algorithmic problems that make me think

Comment: Of course that's the fun. On the other hand, it's also about learning. Simply copying another's solution is not the point, but making it your own and understanding the issue is. Painters can learn from copying the old masters; programmers can learn from looking at great code.